# SourceTree and BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

I installed Git and SourceTree. I have account at Bitbucket and I would like to link to BitBucket from SourceTree. When I enter username and password I get the following error message:

```
The website declined to show this webpage
HTTP 403 
Most likely causes:
•This website requires you to log in.
What you can try:
Go back to the previous page.
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot?

Comment: According to the [Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-sourcetree-603488472.html) it's supposed to work. (Not surprising, since both BitBucket and SourceTree are their products.) Do you have some sort of proxy setup you need to deal with?

Comment: @TedHopp Thank you! It looks like BitBucket and Atlassian have two different logins. I do have account at BitBucket, but not at Atlassian.

Comment: I Faced the Similar issue, While you Installing the Source Tree it ask for Atlassian Login, you have to configure you BitBucket when ever you perform the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using email instead of username.